# VS Code not attaching to ASP.Net 5 on Windows 7

Tags: visual-studio-code

VSCode is not able to neither launch nor attach to the ASP.Net 5 project. I am able to do the same from command prompt successfully. Please see the below screenshot.[image]

Comment: I've the same problem with a node application, did you solved?

Comment: I saw from the documentation V5 debugging is not yet supported in windows platform but I was able to debug node applications. I generated node applications from yeoman generator. https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/nodejs

Comment: I have solved, the problem was mine, I was trying to debug on the 3000 port (node default) but I had to launch the node debugger from the command line and then attach the debugger on the 5858 port (node debug port default)